# Jquery Function not correctly prevent letters from being entered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class called `dateField` Which i assign to inputs that take a date. its supposed to be preventing letters from being inserted and if a user tries to enter a letter it should prevent the action. Its getting into the if that fires the `e.preventDetaul()` however it doesn't actually stop the action.

```
$(document).off('keyup', '.dateField');
$(document).on('keyup', '.dateField', function(e){
    $(this).attr('maxlength', '10');

    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
        (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
         // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    var value=$(this).val();

    if(value.length==2||value.length==5){
        $(this).val($(this).val()+'/');
    }

    if (value.length > 9) {
        var comp = $(this).val().split("/");
        var m = parseInt(comp[0], 10);
        var d = parseInt(comp[1], 10);
        var y = parseInt(comp[2], 10);

        var date = new Date(y,m-1,d);

        if (date.getFullYear() == y && date.getMonth() + 1 == m && date.getDate() == d) {
          $(this).removeClass('fail');
        } else {
          $(this).addClass('fail');
        }
    }

    if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13){
        e.preventDefault();

        if($(this).hasClass('tcal')){
            var date = $(this).val().split("/");
            var m = parseInt(date[0], 10),
            d = parseInt(date[1], 10),
            y = parseInt(date[2], 10);

            if(new Date(y, m - 1, d)!='Invalid Date'){
                //alert( new Date(y, m - 1, d));
                $('.date-manage').mouseleave();
                $('.date.sub-title').html($('#date-between').val()+' to '+$('#date-and').val());

                //$(".box-date input").unbind("blur");
            }
        }

        $('.date-animation').stop();
        $('.date-animation').animate({height: 0}, 500, 'easeOutQuart');
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: @MalteHartwig Go ahead and answer the question that was it! i didn't even think of that lol.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a date picker?

Comment: @Ishettyl its not visually appealing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried other events like keydown? Maybe keyup is too late and the char has already been inserted in the input.